# vue i18n not translate messages when locale is changed

Tags: vue.js, electron, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm using vue i18n to add translation to my vue app anyway after installed the cli plugin and created the translation files inside the `locales` folder I'm unable to switch between translations.

This is the code I've added to the navigation menu

```
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label class="px-2" for=""><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="$i18n.locale">
            <option v-for="(lang, i) in langs" :key="i" :value="lang">{{ lang }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

And this is the realtive js code:

```
<script>
import bus from './main'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
      langs: ['en', 'it']
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    bus.$on('closeMenu', () => {
      this.isVisible = false;
    });
  },
  methods: {
   ...
  }
}
</script>
```

I was expecting that when the user select a different locale the ui is translated but this will not happen.

The content inside my localization json file is this

```
// locales/en.json
{
  "menuLabels": {
    "loadFiles": "Load files",
    "deleteFile": "Delete files",
    "checkFile": "Check file"
  }
}

// locales/it.json
{
  "menuLabels": {
    "loadFiles": "Carica files",
    "deleteFile": "Elimina files",
    "checkFile": "Controlla file"
  }
}
```

into the view where I need to display the translation I've added the correct code by calling the respective translation in this way `<p>{{ $t("message.loadFiles") }}</p>`
Is there any problem with the code?

Comment: Your translation key is `message.loadFiles`, but your localization files show that the root key should be `menuLabels`, so the translation key should be `menuLabels.loadFiles`.

Comment: thank you for the help, I will fix this error.